# Writing a simple Ruby debugger

Tags: ruby, debugging

I'm thinking of writing a basic Ruby debugger (interactive). Can you direct me to some resources or projects to learn more from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you mean a Ruby debugger implemented in Ruby. A good place to start would be to take a look at the introspection and reflection interfaces documented [here](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/)

If you want to be a bit more adventurous you could look at the source for ruby-debug

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm already browsing the ruby-debug code. Also I'm using jruby - does it affect your answer in any way? (Sorry for poor english)

Answer (score 4):

A simple introduction into debuggers: http://t-a-w.blogspot.com/2007/03/how-to-code-debuggers.html. 
 It even has a small part using ruby hashes as an example.

Comment: Nice link, really interesting.

Comment: Thank you! But this doesn't help me much as I use JRuby :(

Comment: Oh well. Maybe someone else reading the question will find it useful.